# Flutter Web Error: Expected a value of type 'Object', but got one of type 'Null' #115332

Tags: javascript, flutter, web, native

Error while running flutter on web

I think the error is coming from firebase core. my project runs smoothly on android.

**Error: Expected a value of type 'Object', but got one of type 'Null'**

**Error output**

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'Object', but got one of type 'Null'

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49 throw_ C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 99:3 castError C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 470:10 cast C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 73:24 as packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 64:20 get \[\_ignoredServiceScripts\] packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 115:28 \_initializeCore C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 85:54 runBody C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 124:5 \_async packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 107:31 \[\_initializeCore\] packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 149:11 initializeApp C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 85:54 runBody C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 124:5 \_async packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 145:44 initializeApp packages/firebase_core/src/firebase.dart 43:47 initializeApp C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 85:54 runBody C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 124:5 \_async packages/firebase_core/src/firebase.dart 39:43 initializeApp packages/swivenetworkproject/main.dart 28:18 main C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 85:54 runBody C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 124:5 \_async packages/swivenetworkproject/main.dart 26:18 main$ web_entrypoint.dart 24:31 \<fn\> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 352:37 \_checkAndCall C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 357:39 dcall C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/lib/ui/initialization.dart 77:15 \<fn\> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 46:50 \<fn\> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1660:54 runUnary C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18 handleValue C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44 handleValueCallback C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13 \_propagateToListeners C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 567:5 \[\_completeWithValue\] C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 640:7 callback C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11 \_microtaskLoop C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5 \_startMicrotaskLoop C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/\_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 167:15 \<fn\>
```

**Flutter doctor -v output**

```
\[√\] Flutter (Channel master, 3.5.0-10.0.pre.58, on Microsoft Windows \[Version 10.0.19043.2251\], locale tr-TR) • Flutter version 3.5.0-10.0.pre.58 on channel master at C:\\src\\flutter • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git • Framework revision 0c14308404 (3 weeks ago), 2022-10-24 14:31:17 -0700 • Engine revision f445898c1a • Dart version 2.19.0 (build 2.19.0-330.0.dev) • DevTools version 2.18.0

\[√\] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

\[√\] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3) • Android SDK at C:\\Users\\monst\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3 • Java binary at: C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio\\jre\\bin\\java • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822) • All Android licenses accepted.

\[√\] Chrome - develop for the web • Chrome at C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe

\[!\] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Derleme Araçları 2019 16.11.18) • Visual Studio at C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools • Visual Studio Derleme Araçları 2019 version 16.11.32802.440 X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these components: MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest C++ CMake tools for Windows Windows 10 SDK

\[√\] Android Studio (version 2021.1) • Android Studio at C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio • Flutter plugin can be installed from: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter • Dart plugin can be installed from: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

\[√\] VS Code (version 1.73.1) • VS Code at C:\\Users\\monst\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code • Flutter extension version 3.52.0

\[√\] Connected device (3 available) • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64 • Microsoft Windows \[Version 10.0.19043.2251\] • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.107 • Edge (web) • edge • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 107.0.1418.42

\[√\] HTTP Host Availability • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

**My pubspec.yaml packages**

```
\#db
firebase_auth: ^4.1.2
firebase_core: ^2.2.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.5
cloud_firestore: ^4.0.2
firebase_database: ^10.0.1
firebase_messaging: ^14.1.0
\#web
firebase_core_web: ^2.0.1
firebase_analytics_web: ^0.5.1+4
firebase_auth_web: ^5.1.2
firebase_messaging_web: ^3.2.6
cloud_firestore_web: ^3.0.5
```

[image]

Output from flutter_core_web

[image]

Comment: I think you don't need to add web packages manually, if you control pubspec.lock, you will see they are already added. I have the same issue by the way, no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

The `_ignoredServiceScripts` getter code snippet shows a try-catch, so it should not be throwing an error.

You should set breakpoints for uncaught exceptions rather than all exceptions.

If you are using VSCode on the debug panel you will see the options when you start the debugger and it looks like this:
[breakpoint in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBh3o.png)

Failing that, make sure that your Firebase configuration is set up correctly according to the [official instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup).

See also [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10009#issuecomment-1333208524).
Hopefully, that should resolve the issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34422127)